# Windsor Typed Factory facility, passing arguments when using singleton lifestyle

Tags: singleton, castle-windsor, typed-factory-facility

I am using [Castle Windsor](http://www.castleproject.org/container/).

I have two component types where the implementation can be selected at runtime on a GUI.  To handle this, I am resolving them by name.  To handle resolving them by name, I am using the [Typed Factory Facility](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Typed-Factory-Facility.ashx).

One of the component types depends on the other.  To handle the dependency, I am passing the argument as a factory method/constructor parameter argument.

Here is a redacted and abridged version of this factory interface:

```
public interface IModelFactory
{
    IMyDomainCommandFactory GetFooCommandFactory();
    IMyDomainCommandFactory GetBarCommandFactory();
    IMyDomainStrategy GetCreateSpecificSizeStrategy(int size, IMyDomainCommandFactory commandFactory);
    IMyDomainStrategy GetCreateUntilFailureStrategy(IMyDomainCommandFactory commandFactory);
}
```

Note that I am using my own implementations for `IMyDomainCommandFactory`, rather than using the Typed Factory facility.  Those factories have intentionally complex behavior, and the facility doesn't suit their needs.

The problem I am noticing is that if I register my strategy components with a singleton lifestyle, I always get back the same instance, even if I pass different arguments to the getter.

In my opinion, this goes against the [Principal of Least Astonishment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment), but maybe other people have a different opinion :)  Should this be considered a bug?

If not, is there a clean way to get the container or factory to create only one instance per argument combination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending how you look at it, but certainly instance per combination of parameters can't be called a singleton so I say it would go against PoLA if Windsor did implement the behavior you'd expect.

If you want it, you need a custom, non-singleton lifestyle.

Comment: Okay, now that I think about it a bit more, you're right.  This can be expected for a Singleton.  So, maybe the problem is that singleton isn't a perfect default option when coupled with the factory facility.  Or maybe I'm just new to IoC ;)  Can you link to the preferred custom lifestyle doc in your answer?  I am seeing two sets of docs, and I'm not sure which one is preferred for linking.

Comment: http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.LifeStyles.ashx or http://www.castleproject.org/container/documentation/v1rc3/usersguide/lifestyles.html ?  Also, it turns out that I was binding up dependencies too early, and that's causing the problem :)  I can modify the methods of `IMyDomainStrategy` to take `IMyDomainCommandFactory` and avoid this whole mess.

Comment: @Merlyn Morgan-Graham re: docs - the new one obviously. The old one is going to be removed completely.

Comment: re "singleton isn't a perfect default option when coupled with the factory facility" <-- nothing about the component couples it to the factory. You *can* use it with a factory like any other component, and you can use it without factory like any other component.